# Fullcalendar addEventSource Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, fullcalendar

I want to add an EventSource of an Array. i created a String over an ajax callthat looks like this:

```
Public Shared Function Test() As String
        Dim EventArray As New ArrayList

        Dim EventSource As String = "[{"
        EventSource += "title:  'All Day Event',"
        EventSource += "start: '2012-07-01'"
        EventSource += "},"
        EventSource += "{"
        EventSource += "title: 'Long Event',"
        EventSource += "start: '2012-07-25',"
        EventSource += "end: '2012-07-28'"
        EventSource += "},"
        EventSource += "{"
        EventSource += "id: 999,"
        EventSource += "title:  'Repeating Event',"
        EventSource += "start: '2012-07-27 16:00:00',"
        EventSource += "allDay: false"
        EventSource += "},"
        EventSource += "{"
        EventSource += "id: 999,"
        EventSource += "title: 'Repeating Event',"
        EventSource += "start: '2012-08-04 16:00:00',"
        EventSource += "allDay: false"
        EventSource += "},"
        EventSource += "{"
        EventSource += "title: 'Meeting',"
        EventSource += "start: '2012-07-30 10:30:00',"
        EventSource += "allDay: false"
        EventSource += "},"
        EventSource += "{"
        EventSource += "title: 'Lunch',"
        EventSource += "start: '2012-07-30 12:00:00',"
        EventSource += "end: '2012-07-30 14:00:00',"
        EventSource += "allDay: false"
        EventSource += "},"
        EventSource += "{"
        EventSource += "title: 'Birthday Party',"
        EventSource += "start: '2012-07-31 19:00:00',"
        EventSource += "end: '2012-07-31 22:30:00',"
        EventSource += "allDay: false"
        EventSource += "},"
        EventSource += "{"
        EventSource += "title: 'Click for Google',"
        EventSource += "start: '2012-07-28',"
        EventSource += "end: '2012-07-29',"
        EventSource += "url: 'http://google.com/'"
        EventSource += "}]"



        Return EventSource
    End Function
```

and I tried to add the Array like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        dayClick: function(date) {
        alert(date);
    },
    editable: true

    });
    $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'KalenderEvents.aspx/Test',
                    data: '{}',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (msg) {
                    var events = msg.d || []
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource','events:' + events);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
                    }
                });
   });
```

If i remove 'events:' the code trys to execute an JSON Feed...
else he just don't show anything. ajax call get executed normally.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `events:` in the `addEventSource`. FullCalendar should accept a JSON array properly.

Comment: thats the problem...
If I just give him the String:
"[{title: 'titletext', start: '2012-03-05'},{...}]"
he trys to call an url which results in a "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request"...
And I just can't see were I (did?) go wrong... =(

Comment: Have you tried using `eventSources`? You can use `$.ajax` right inside the FullCalendar init - http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/
Maybe that'll help solve this.

Comment: Not yet, reason is that i want to add / remove the sources out of the fullcalendar init.
I try it now, just to check if it works ;-)

Comment: Is there a wrong way of thinking, if I only want to add the eventsource only once? Should I change my serversidecode into one that accepts the parameters the fullcalender gives to the url and only generate events that are actually needed only for the month that are being shown?
I don't know why he shouldn't accept an Array over an eventsource but works when i add the String under the init manually which is completly wrong for what I need to do....